# Can't find the Android SDK tools setup wizard

Tags: android, intellij-idea

I want to use IntelliJ to make an Andorid application. Currently, I am trying to set up the project, and am following this tutorial:

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/prerequisites-for-android-development.html

I downloaded the SDK tools-zip, and now the tutorial says to: "use the installer to launch the Android SDK Tools Setup wizard". However, I am not able to find the installer anywhere in the "tools"-folder. Below is a picture of how the "tools"-folder looks like.

[image]

Does anyone know where to find the installer?

Thanks!

Comment: Hm do you mean the platform tools? Besides that why not use Android Studio? It's based on IntelliJ anyways.

Comment: Thank you! I might just change to Android Studio, it seems simpler to set up

Comment: You really should do that. It comes with android specific tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]You will find it in your SDK Root directory.
e.g D:\Android_SDK\SDK Manager.exe.
Launch SDK Manager.exe you will find the SDK Setup page.

Comment: Thank you so much :)! I tried running the SDK Manager, it was under tools/lib, unfortunately I get the following error when I run the SDK Manager: 

"failed to execute tools\android.bat: The system can not find the file specified"

Do you perhaps know what to do about this?

Comment: Have you run SDK Manager.exe? It will be in your root folder not inside the tools/lib folder.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have no SDK Manager.exe in the root folder, only in the tools/lib folder. That is the SDK Manager.exe that I have run.

You can see my root folder in the above image, if that helps

Comment: Thank you for the image, my root folder does not look the same, which makes me think I somehow installed the wrong thing, and not the Android SDK. I installed the command line tools from here: https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html  

These should include the Android SDK, but I can't find it, so I will try another installation

Comment: Just run your android studio that you have downloaded. It will ask you to download the Android API.